# Becoming PCB designer

Tags: pcb-design

I am an Engineering Technician, I have been soldering and de-soldering in years. I have designed and home-made toner transfer PCB as well. Now I am thinking to take course for professional PCB design for my career. I am wondering which courses I should take. Did anyone take this course, is it good for beginners? Or any recommendation?

Thank You in advance!

https://www.ipc.org/ContentPage.aspx?pageid=Introduction-to-Printed-Circuit-Board-Design&fbclid=IwAR26e0crfolD7DEC6-ZTzWs7u_n45AJducaTSSb23PNj9hyxYBRhE1ajUSQ

Comment: If you're just worried about fabrication and quality of the PCB, then you should talk to your engineers and ask them about it first.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at Kicad. It's an open-source cross-platform program where you can design your schematic, PCB and a 3D rendering of the PCB. You can also simulate your schematics in `spice`.

Kicad itself has some great tutorials from beginners to more expert tutorials.

[Kicad tutorials - Wayback Machine link to old website](https://web.archive.org/web/20200422141802/https://kicad-pcb.org/help/tutorials/)

[Kicad tutorials - current website](https://www.kicad.org/help/learning-resources/)

Did I say it's free?